# Can you write to a text file and then read from that same text file in the same program?

Tags: python, text-files

Basically I want to be able to calculate a parameter store it was a text file then read it back in later in the program.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried?

Comment: Just remember that reading/writing to a disk will be slower than storing in RAM. If there are a lot of reading/writing you should really store it in memory and write when the program close or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
myFile = 'example.txt'
```

Using `with` will automatically close the file when you leave that structure

```
# perform your writing
with open(myFile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('some stuff')

# doing other work
# more code

# perform your reading
with open(myFile, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    # do stuff with data
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `close()` before changing mode (read / write):

```
def MyWrite(myfile):
    file = open(myfile, "w")    
    file.write("hello world in the new file\n")   
    file.close()

def MyRead(myfile):
    file = open(myfile, "r")
    file.read()
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could open a file for reading AND writing, using:

```
fd = open(myfile, "r+")
```

However, you must be **very careful**, since every operation, either read or write, changes the pointer position, so you may need to use fd.seek to make sure you're placed in the right position where you want to read or write.

Also, keep in mind that your file becomes a sort of memory mapped string(*) that sometimes syncs with the disk. If you want to save changes at a specific point, you must use fd.flush and os.fsync(fd) to efectively commit the changes to disk without closing the file.

All in all, I'd say its better to stick to one mode of operation and then closing the file and opening again, unless there's a very good reason to have read/write available without switching modes.

* There's also a module for memory mapped files, but I think thats way beyond what you were asking.